# Merge three arrays in Python3

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, merge

I have three arrays:

```
arr1 = ['name1', 'name2', ...]
arr2 = ['192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2', ...]
arr3 = ['port1', 'port2', ...]
```

I would like to merge them in one like this:

```
final_arr = ['name1', '192.168.1.1', 'port1', 'name2', '192.168.1.2', 'port2', ...]
```

I tried with **dict.fromkeys()** but doesn't seem to be the answer ...

If you had any idea?

Thanks!!

Comment: look into `zip()` and comprehensions for flattening

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this:

```
arr1 = ['name1', 'name2']
arr2 = ['192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2']
arr3 = ['port1', 'port2']

arr = [y for x in zip(arr1, arr2, arr3) for y in x]
# ['name1', '192.168.1.1', 'port1', 'name2', '192.168.1.2', 'port2']
```

Comment: This solution returns something like this: `['name1', '192.168.1.1', 'port1', 'name2', '192.168.1.2', 'port2']` ... Just what I was expecting ... THANKS!!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same length for the three array you can just make a for loop like that :

```py
arr1 = ['name1', 'name2']
arr2 = ['192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2']
arr3 = ['port1', 'port2']
arr = []

for i in range(0, len(arr1)):
  arr.extend([arr1[i], arr2[i], arr3[i]])

print(arr)
```

Comment: It is a good option too. THANKS to both of you!!!